# provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, wcf

Deseo saber si, ¿alguien de ustedes ha encontrado este problema? Y ¿Cómo lo han solventado?. De antemano muchas gracias. Esto esta en **SQL server** y **ASP.Net**

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
>     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
>     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
>     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
>     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
>     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

Comment: Fran91, bienvenido@ a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Que codigo te da el error? Considera leer el articulo [mcve] y despues [edit] tu pregunta para incluir el codigo que genera este error.

Comment: Ahi dice que no ve la base de datos. puede que no este recibiendo conexiones u otra cosa. verifica eso.

Comment: Hola Kenny Barrera me da error en dos clases que hacen conexion con la base de datos

Comment: Hola gbianchi algo que no mencione pero estoy haciendo una mitigacion de protocolo y acabo de colocar la linea para activar el protocolo TLS 1.2 en mi maquina y no se si ese me esta afectando en la conexion

Comment: Revisaste que los puertos para SQL estén abiertos? que realmente llegas a la maquina? en muchas de las migraciones he visto estos problemas....claramente el error indica que no puedes acceder a la base de datos.

Comment: Hola ese error si estas trabajando de forma local, primero debes tener abierto los puertos del sql, segundo ver que tu servicio de sqlserver este levantado en el administrador de configuración de sql, tercero, fijate de no haber cambiado la dirección del servidor en tu webconfig, porque si pasaste de local a servidor web debe haber cambiado la dirección.